# Expectation in reversible Markov chain

Tags: probability, expectation, markov-chains, conditional-expectation, markov-process

Let $X$ be a Markov chain with transition matrix:
$$\mathbf{P}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{3}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \\ \frac{3}{4} & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\ \frac{2}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0\end{pmatrix}\;\;\text{and initial distribution}\;\pi=\tfrac{1}{12}(5,4,3)$$
Let $\tau (i,j)=\inf \big\{n:\;\{i,j\}\,\text{is a subsequence of}\, \{X_0,\dots,X_n\}\big\}$. I am trying to:

- show $\mathbb{E}[\tau(1,2)]=\mathbb{E}[\tau(2,1)]$
- show $\mathbb{E}_1[T_2]-\mathbb{E}_2[T_1]=\sum_i \pi_i\left(\mathbb{E}_i[T_1]-\mathbb{E}_i[T_2]\right)$

(where $T_k=\inf \{m\geqslant 1:\;X_m=k\}$ is the first passage time at $k$)

---

So far I have shown that $\mathbf{P},\pi$ are in detailed balance, so the chain is reversible, and hence the distribution of $\{X_0,\dots,X_n\}$is the same as that of $\{X_n,\dots, X_0\}$. So some sort of symmetry argument might be used to prove the first part, but I am not sure how.

For the second part,  the RHS are conditioned expectations, so we can write it as $\mathbb{E}[T_1]-\mathbb{E}[T_2]$. Again I think I'm missing something relatively basic but I cannot see why this is the same as $\mathbb{E}_1[T_2]-\mathbb{E}_2[T_1]$.

It would be really helpful if someone could give me a nudge...

Comment: Isn't it true that $\tau(1,2)=\tau(2,1)$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins $\{i,j\}$ is interpreted as a sequence/ordered set I think, so it isn't immediately true.

Comment: So "$\{i,j\}\subseteq\{X_0,\ldots,X_n\}$" is intended to mean "$\{i,j\}$ is a subsequence of $\{X_0,\ldots,X_n\}$".

Comment: @JohnDawkins Sorry yes, fixed now.

Comment: Another clarification, please: in the definition of $\tau(1,2)$, is it $\inf\{n\ge 0:\ldots$ or $\inf\{n\ge 1: \ldots$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins $n\geqslant 1$ I guess, though I don't think it makes a difference since $\tau$ cannot be $0$?

Comment: But $\tau(1,2)$ is the first time to visit $2$ after having previously visited $1$, and if the chain starts in state $1$, then it matters whether time $n=0$ counts or not.

Comment: @JohnDawkins The question says (quote): "Let $\tau(i,j)$ be the
least $n$ such that $\{i, j\}$ appears as a subsequence of $\{X_0,X_1\dots X_n\}$". Sorry about if my definition wasn't clear

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following extension of $\tau(1,2)$: At time $\tau(1,2)$, choose a target state at random (with distribution $\pi$, independent of what has gone before)  and continue until the first time that state is hit. The mean time for this total trip is $\Bbb E[\tau(1,2)]+\sum_j \Bbb E_2[D_j]\pi_j=\Bbb E[\tau(1,2)]+K$. Here $D_j:=\inf\{n\ge 0: X_n=j\}$, and $K:=\sum_{j}\Bbb E_i[D_j]\pi_j$ is *Kemeny's Constant*, and does not depend on the  state $i$. 
Running this trip in reverse (which does not change its expected value) corresponds to starting with distribution $\pi$, running until time $\tau(2,1)$, and then picking a target with law $\pi$ independently of what has gone before, and then stopping when that target is hit. This reverse trip has meanvalue $\Bbb E[\tau(2,1)]+K$ by the previous reasoning and reversibility. It follows that $\Bbb E[\tau(1,2)]=\Bbb E[\tau(2,,1)]$.

The second assertion should follow by subtraction because $\tau(1,2)=D_1+T_2\circ\theta_{D_1}$ and $\tau(2,1)=D_2+T_1\circ\theta_{D_2}$. (Here $\theta_n$ is the time shift operator on path space of the Markov chain.) Thus
$$
\Bbb E[D_1]+\Bbb E_1[T_2]=\Bbb E[D_2]+\Bbb E_2[T_1].
$$